# Replace %20 in url with "_" .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can i rewrite the url further for %20 to be replaced with _ .
Here is my current url:

```
localhost/car-86-Honda%20Accord%202019
```

here is the code i have used before.

```
RewriteRule ^car-([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ ncarposts.php?carpostid=$1&title=$2
```

I have tried searching but there's no solution for this common issue we have used in our urls...

complete code is:

```
# Rewrite for ncarposts.php?carpostid=83&?title=Toyota%20Land%20Cruiser%202019
RewriteRule ^car-([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ ncarposts.php?carpostid=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: why do you need that by the way?

Comment: to make url clean and user friendly

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know the the RewriteRule matches with decoded url, so you may try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1_$2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1_$2 [L]

# remove multiple underscore
RewriteRule ^(.*)_{2,}(.*)$ /$1_$2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: `
# Rewrite for ncarposts.php?carpostid=83&?title=Toyota%20Land%20Cruiser%202019

RewriteRule ^car-([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ ncarposts.php?carpostid=$1&title=$2



RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1_$2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1_$2 [L]

# remove multiple underscore
RewriteRule ^(.*)_{2,}(.*)$ /$1_$2 [L,R=302]
`

Comment: you cannot do it this way you posted it. try to use it as I provided it.